" As" or " for" for this sentence
I'm writing some scale model painting guidelines and came across this dilemma.
The phrase in question is the following:

Try, as much as possible, to use commercially available colors as the main colors of the model

Should I have said?

Try, as much as possible, to use commercially available colors for the main colors of the model

The idea behind it is that you should try to use a commercially available color instead of a mixture of colors of your own make.
Thanks

I'd say neither presents a problem. 'For' would be my choice, as it suggests instrumentality and fits with the possible non-availability neatly.

Using as goes with thinking of both occurrences of color as having exactly the same sense, while using for goes with thinking of its first occurrence as standing for paint. But, as Mr Ashworth has already suggested, you may be overthinking the matter: either formulation will work OK for most ends and purposes.

If the sentence is simplified to "Try to use commercially available colors for the model" the choice is easier.

What is the reasoning?   Matching the custom color later on could be difficult?  As it stands, the advice is unexplained.  But "use ... colors ... for|as the main colors" is a tad awkward.  I think the sentence should be reworked.  You could say "Using commercially available paints for the main colors is advisable because _____".

For sounds more natural to me. And based on this experiment, I’d go with for just to be safe... ? As the main colors of the model, try to use commercially available colors vs. For the main colors of the model, try to use commercially available colors....

It is to some extent a matter of style, but I think "as" is used when you're talking about an implement or a whole ("Use this as a hammer", "A hermit crab uses a found object as a home") while "for" is used when talking about a contribution to a larger thing ("Use this paint for your craft project", "Use this money for your holiday").
